# keyError in python when using networkx package to visualize data

Tags: python, twitter, networkx

I'm trying to download twitter account and followers information trying to visualize the data by creating a relationship graph with Networkx python package and Gaphi.

```
    import networkx as nx
    import MySQLdb

    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                 user="root", # your username
                  passwd="123456", # your password
                  db="twitterbank") # name of the data base
    cur = conn.cursor()

    def get_user_info(m):
        cur.execute("SELECT tweeter_name FROM tweets_fetch where tweeter_id=%s" %m)

    g=nx.Graph()

    def add_node_tw(n,weight=None,time=None,location=None):
        if not g.has_node(n):
            screen_name=get_user_info(n)
            g.add_node(n)
            g.node[n]['weight']=1
            g.node[n]["screen_name"]=screen_name
        else:
            g.node[n]['weight']+=1

    def add_edge_tw(n1,n2,weight=None):
        if not g.has_edge(n1,n2):
            g.add_edge(n1,n2)
            g[n1][n2]['weight']=1
        else:
            g[n1][n2]['weight']+=1

    #generate set of users

     users=set()
     cur.execute("SELECT distinct tweeter_id FROM tweets_fetch")
     cur.fetchall() 
     for row in cur:  
          users.add(row[0])


    g=nx.DiGraph()

    for u_id in users:
        add_node_tw(u_id)
        cur.execute("select * from tweeter_followers where tweeter_id=%s" %u_id)
        cur.fetchall()
        for row1 in cur:
            if row1[0] in users:
                add_node_tw(row1[0])
                add_edge_tw(row1[0],row1[1])
    nx.write_graphml(g,'relationship_graphml')
```

Two tables I have created with downloaded data are:
 
`tweets_fetch: with columns (tweeter_id, tweeter_name, tweet_content, datetime...)`
`tweeter_followers: with columns (tweeter_id, follower_id)`

When I execute the above code, errors pop out as below:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Sepups\eclipse-SDK-3.7.1-win32-    x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.3.2013031601\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1397, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
    File "D:\Sepups\eclipse-SDK-3.7.1-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.3.2013031601\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1090, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script
    File "D:\java\python\workspace\tweetsHarvest\src\tweet_graph.py", line 47, in <module>
    add_node_tw(u_id)
    File "D:\java\python\workspace\tweetsHarvest\src\tweet_graph.py", line 24, in add_node_tw
    g.node[n]['weight']+=1
    KeyError: 'weight'
```

Anyone knows how to fix it? I'm really a newbie to python and Gephi. I blog I referred when creating my code is http://giladlotan.com/blog/mapping-twitters-python-data-science-communities/

Answer (score 0):

I created a script based off the same code and had the same error using one data set in particular. If you're having the same problem as me, there is some issue with a few of the rows in your data. For me, it was just a handful out of several thousand edges. To diagnose where the problems are, you could print out each row right before the add_edge_tw statement, and add in a try/except clause before add_edge_tw.

I am sure others who are better at Python and NetworkX can give a better answer but hope this helps with a quick fix while you diagnose.